# Create mupltiple models at a time DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I know there are similar questions like this but I've gone through them all and didn't find the right answer.

I have a `Question` model and `POST` method in my `APIView` looks like this:

```
 def post(self, request):
    """Create a new question"""

    description = request.data['description']
    question_type = request.data['type']
    answers_to_close = request.data['to_close']

    question = Question.objects.create(
        description=description,
        question_type=question_type,
        answers_to_close=answers_to_close
    )

    return Response({
        'status': 'SUCCESS', 'question_id': question.id,
        'message': 'New question has been created successfully!',
        'question': f"'{description}'"
    })
```

It works fine but I also want to add a possibility to create multiple questions within one request. I tried something like this (another instance of `APIView`:

```
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    """Create a session of questions"""

    session = kwargs['session']

    description = request.data['description']
    question_type = request.data['type']
    answers_to_close = request.data['to_close']

    Question.objects.create(
        description=description,
        question_type=question_type,
        answers_to_close=answers_to_close,
        session=session
    )

    return Response({
        'status': 'SUCCESS', 'session': session,
        'message': 'A new session has been created!'
    })
```

So when I try this curl request:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/sessions/create/21383/ --data 
['description=Am I Strong&type=YESNO&to_close=3', 'description=Best js 
framework&type=TEXT&to_close=10']
```

It says `django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'description' '`

What's wrong with me `APIView`?

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37329771/django-rest-bulk-post-post-array-of-json-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You need to define a serializer with create method, then use from this serializer class in your view, like following

```
class QuestionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('description', 'question_type', 'answers_to_close',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        Question.objects.create(description=validated_data['description'],
                                question_type=validated_data['question_type'],
                               answers_to_close=validated_data['answers_to_close'])
        return validated_data



class QuestionAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```